# 404 Not found : Could not find the controller. Services module

Tags: services

I have installed [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module and enabled `Resource-> node`. Now i am using postman to test default services. My configuration details:
endpoint is "apis". Server is "REST". localhost url `http://drupaltest.localhost.com`. Also as per given in README file, i have downloaded spyc.php file and placed into servers/rest_server/lib/.

So when i am calling api `http://drupaltest.localhost.com/apis/node` its showing me result. when i am calling 
`http://drupaltest.localhost.com/apis/node/retrieve`, 
i am getting error: `404 Not found : Node retrieve could not be found`.
And for `http://drupaltest.localhost.com/apis/node/create error: 404 Not found : Could not find the controller`.

Is there i am missing any configuration or any permission issue?

Comment: Retrieve is not a thing, you should enter a node id (nid) on that spot: `http://drupaltest.localhost.com/apis/node/1`. I suppose the create fails because it does not support GET, but needs data to be POST-ed to it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not have been part of your issue, as I also think a node id should be where you wrote `retrieve`. But regarding `spyc.php`, I noticed that this file should be placed at `sites/all/libraries/spyc/spyc.php` or you will get an error message on your status page.